# Jquery trigger div height change event (animate?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to detect the total height of my div "collectionFilterPage" while the animate event is running. Is there any event to bind?
This is my ja code:

```
function showMoreItems() {
    $("#collectionFilterPage").animate({
        height: "+=720"
    }, 1000, function() {
        if ($("#collectionFilterPage").outerHeight() >= $(".lista").outerHeight())
            unbindScrollEvent();
    });
}
```

Basically I would want to fire the "unbindScrollEvent" when both div "collectionFilterPage" and "lista" have the same height.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to switch to this `$().aninate` signature and use the `step` property which allows you to set a callback function that is called during each step of the animation.

```
function showMoreItems() {
    function checkHeight() {
        if ($("#collectionFilterPage").outerHeight() >= $(".lista").outerHeight())
            unbindScrollEvent();
    }

    $("#collectionFilterPage").animate({
        height: "+=720"
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: checkHeight,
        step: checkHeight
    });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$(...).animate( properties, options );
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It has been very easy

> height: $("#collectionFilterPage").outerHeight() >=
>   $(".lista").outerHeight() ? "+=0" : "+=720"